# Is Hanuman the 11th Rudra?

Tags: shiva, hanuman

Many of us here claims that Lord Hanuman was one of the Rudra (especially people say Hanuman is 11th Rudra).As it is said in many of our scriptures and puranas that Hanuman was an incarnation/avatar of Shiva.

But on the other side, in an answer to my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20540/how-many-rudras-have-been-actually-born/20545#20545), Tezz refers to the Ekadasha Rudras and Ashta Murti Rudras, none of them has Hanuman's name mentioned. So, what is relation between Rudra and Hanuman?  If this was not the case, if Hanuman was not the Rudra, then who was he ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Hanuman an avatar of Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8318/is-hanuman-an-avatar-of-lord-shiva)

Comment: Rudras are divine beings. They don't have Physical bodies. Hanuman has Physical body.

Comment: @Vishwas I have edited question so that it doesn't become duplicate and your question why Hanuman is called 11th Rudra is adressed... Are you fine with the Edit?...

Comment: @thedestroyer Rama also had physical body, so? Rudra took birth as Hanuman. If rudra will take birth then ofcourse he will have a body.

Comment: @Rishabh I think Devas don't have physical bodies but their incarnations do. Why we are not able to see Shiva on Kailasa through satellite? Because he is present there is suksma form which we can only see through yoga or if he manifests on his on will.  Hanuman and Rama have physical bodies.

Comment: @thedestroyer This is what I said. You was saying rudra dont have physical bodies but Hanuman has. Was your mean Hanuman is not rudra since he has physical body? Shiva's rudra took birth as Hanuman.

Comment: @Rishabh you mean to say that Hanuman was an incarnation of Rudra and not Shiva directly ? if yes then which one from the Rudras incarnated as Hanuman?

Comment: @vishwasgoswami Hanuman is ansh avatar of shiva. And rudra is ansh of shiva. So if rudra will take birth then he will be considered as ansh avatar of Shiva. And I already told you that 11th rudra is Hanuman as per my knowledge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many Rudras have been actually born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20540/how-many-rudras-have-been-actually-born). According to famous interpretations (e.g. Gambhirananda), lord Hanuman doesn't belong to the list of 11 Rudra-s. See [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20541/1049).

Comment: @iammilind  **lord Hanuman doesn't belong to the list of 11 Rudra-s**. What do you mean by **list** here. The list you are showing that list being created before Hanuman's birth. If any of rudra will take birth even then that list won't change because this list is not of incarnations as simple as that. So this list can't decide whether Hanuman is any of the rudra or not. What If we make list of Tridev and later you might say Rama is not among tridev coz he is not present in list of Tridev lol.

Comment: @all, for one moment i agree with you that lord Hanuman was not a Rudra. But, in one of the scriptures i read that when the great Ravana was on his death bed, counting his last breaths, He himself told that " Oh great Hanuman, forgive me. I despite of being one of the greatest devotee of shiva, couldn't identify you, the 11th Rudra himself "

i don't remember where exactly i read this but probably it was somewhere in Ramayana.

Comment: ".As it is said in many of our scriptures and puranas that Hanuman was an incarnation/avatar of Shiva." This is not true. There is just 1 reference in the Shiva purana. Two other references show Pavan  deva as the original deva.

Answer (score 6):

No, Hanuman isn't among the 11 Rudras. I discuss 11 Rudras and their significances in my [answer here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7954/why-did-lord-shiva-take-44-avatars-if-his-primary-role-is-to-be-the-destroyer/16687#16687)

The 11 Rudras are:

> They were **Mrigavayadha, Sarpa, Niriti** of great fame: **Ajaikapat, Ahivradhna, and Pinaki,** the oppressor of foes; **Dahana and Iswara, and Kapali** of great splendour; and **Sthanu, and the illustrious Bharga. These are called the eleven Rudras.** [Adi Parva, Sambhava Parva chapter 66]

Similarly in the Harivamsha Parva of Mahabharata:

> सुरभी कश्यपात् रुद्रान् एकादश विनिर्ममे ।
>   महादेव प्रसादेन तपसा भाविता सती ॥१-३-४९
>   अजैकपाद् अहिर्बुध्न्यः त्वष्टा रुद्राः च भारत ।
>   त्वष्टुः चैव आत्मजः श्रीमान् विश्वरूपो महायशाः १-३-५० 
>   **हरः च बहु-रूपः च त्र्यम्बकः च अपराजितः ।
>
>   वृषा-कपिः च शम्भुः च कपर्दी रैवतः तथा ॥** १-३-५१
>   मृग-व्याधः च सर्पः च कपाली च विशांपते ।
>   एकादश एते कथिता रुद्राः त्रि-भुवन-ईश्वराः ॥१-३-५२  
>   ब्शतं तु एवं समाख्यातं रुद्राणाम् अमित-औजसाम् ।
>   पुराणे भरतश्रेष्ठ यैः व्याप्ताः स चर-अचराः ॥१-३-५३
>  
>   Hallowed by her own ascesis and by the grace of mahadeva, the daughter of daskha prajApati, and the wife of kashyapa prajApati, lady surabhi, moulded eleven rudrA-s. Apart from those eleven rudrA-s, Ajaika-pAd, Ahir-budhnya, TwaShTa, and ruda are also the progeny of surabhi, and tvaShTA's son is the highly glorious vishva-rUpa. Oh, king, **the eleven rudrA-s are: Hara, Bahu-rUpa, Tryambaka, AparAjita, Vrishakapi, Shambhu, Kapardi, Raivata, MrigavyAdha, Sarpa, and KapAli.** Oh, king, purANA-s tell that these eleven highly resplendent rudrA-s, on **manifesting themselves manifoldly, are pervading the subtle bodies of all sessile and mobile beings, and thus they became the controllers of three worlds.**

Thus Hanuman is not among the 11 Rudras. But what is the relation between Rudra and Hanuman? The relation is through the AshtaMurti form of Rudras. Hanuman is son of Vayu. And Vayu (Air) is one among the Eight form (AshtaMurti Roopam) of Shiva. I discuss it [here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10524/whats-the-relation-between-lord-shiva-and-lord-shani-dev/17075#17075)

> सुवर्चला तथैवोमा सुकेशी चापरा शिवा। 
>   स्वाहा दिशस्तथा दीक्षा रोहणी च यथाक्रमम् ॥८॥ 
>   सूर्यादीनां नरश्रेष्ठ रुद्राधैर्नामभिः सह। 
>   पत्न्यः स्मृता महाभाग तदपत्यानि मे शृणु। 
>   येषां सूतिप्रसूतैर्वा इदमापूरितं जगत् ॥ ९ ।। 
>   शनैश्चरस्तथा शुक्रो लोहिताङ्गो मनोजवः। 
>   स्कन्दः खर्गोऽथ सन्तानो बुधश्चानुक्रमात् सुताः॥ १०॥ (Vishnu Purana 1.8) 
>  
>   The wives of the Sun and the other manifestations, termed Rudra and the rest were respectively, Suvercalā, Uma, Vikesi, Sivā, Svāhā, Dišā, Diksā and Rohiņī. Now hear an account of their progeny, by whose successive generations this world has been peopled. **Their sons,** then, were severally, Sanaiśocara (Saturn), Sukra (Venus), the fiery bodied Mars, **Manojava (Hanumān),** Skanda, Swarga, Santana, and Budha (Mercury).

And in Markandeya Purana chapter 52:

> The sun, the water, the earth, the fire, the ether, the initiated Brahman, and the moon, these became respectively their abodes. Suvarchala and similarly Uma, Vikeshi and another, Swadha, Swaha, and likewise Disha, Diksha, Rohini these respectively, O thou superior among the twice-born, became with the sun &c., the possession of the holders of the names commencing with Rudra &c.,. **Their sons** respectively were Shanaishchara, Shukra, Lohitanga, **Monajava,** Skandha, Sarga, Santana, and Budha.

Thus, in this way Hanuman is son of Shiva through his Ashtamurti form of Vãyu (Air). However in Shiva Purana there is a chapter called 'The incarnation of Hanuman', it is told Hanuman is also direct incarnation of Shiva. But in any case Hanuman isn't 11th Rudra.

Comment: *"No, Hanuman isn't among the 11 Rudras"*, that implies that there are 11 Rudra-s. Isn't it contradicting with your [yesterday's answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20545/1049) suggesting infinite number of Rudra-?. :-)

Comment: But Hanuman is considered as Rudransh. Whats the meaning of rudransh if he is not rudra of Shiva. We all use to say that Hanuman is rudra avatar of Shiva. Whats the meaning of rudra avatar of Shiva if he is not rudra?

Comment: And also, you said **Hanuman is son of Vayu**. On what basis? Vayu dev just put shiva's ansh into Mata Anjana by the order of Shiva. Only because of this help of vayu dev, he is considered as father of Hanuman. So Vayu dev is more like Dharm peeta of Hanuman, not real father.

Comment: @iammilind No, there is not contradiction. Among uncountable Rudras there are special groups of Rudras like 11 Rudras, AshtaMurti Rudras etc... also in that answer I have written 'The famous groups are groups of Ekadash Rudras and groups of AshtaMurti Rudras;

Ekadash Rudras are:.... '

Comment: @Tezz, OK I see your point. In general, I have seen references of 11 Rudra-s only. The concept of "infinite Rudra-s" is new to me. Probably, 11 Rudra-s refer to formful Rudra-s (like "lord Shankara"). I am just guessing. May be some day we can take this topic in a chat. :-)

Comment: This makes sense. Hanumanji is the son of Rudra Vayu and not one among the 49 maruts. But I got a doubt after reading again today. Does this mean that Budha was son of Rudra Chandra and not Atreya Chandra (the one who produced Budha with Tara, wife of Brihaspati)? Also when Kartikeya (Lord Shiva’s seed) was given to Agni to bear, does it mean that it was given to Rudra Agni and not Vasu Agni? Same for Shani being Chhaya putra vs Rudrani putra.