# Does Lord Shiva grant wishes?

Tags: shiva, bhakti

Sometimes people have a certain wish that they want to be fulfilled. I've read and heard that God can grant any wish. How does one ask or approach Him to grant a wish. If you chant His name numerous time everyday almost all the day will that work? Sometimes people are in situations where they feel only a miracle can help them and some people believe God can make miracles happen. Is there a particular way to meditate or worship Shiva to ask Him to grant wishes?

Comment: You should do your Dharma (duty). You can't expect Shiva to fulfill your wishes without performing **Swadharma**.

Comment: The Lord does not grant wishes; saints and gods will grant wishes. The Lord only grants Liberation.

Comment: Swami Vivekananda calls this shopkeeping religion. See his lecture entitled Formal Worship (Complete Works, V6, pp 66-67, available here under the heading Lectures and Discourses, sub-heading Formal Worship - http://cwsv.belurmath.org/volume_6/vol_6_frame.htm)

Comment: First of all I'm sorry as this is my first time so I made some mistakes in posting the question. @The Destroyer I understand what you said and it is totally true, however the wish I have is not something I or any human can do anything about. It is of my brother's mental condition which is apparently out of hands where doctors gave up and I can't see him that way so  seek God for help. Speaking of my Dharma it hurts too much to see him that way to be able to focus on something else so I've been visiting temples and trying to seek help from the God himself.

Comment: @Swami vishwananda I've read the article you posted and I see mine isn't the greatest way of worshipping God but I'm in no state to seek liberation or enlightenment. I'm a simple man with a problem which apparently cannot be solved by human power so I need the help of the God. It maybe materialistic and low level worship but I cannot help seeing my people suffer in front of my eyes while I go educating myself about ways of worshipping. About lord and god, there are many stories or Lord Shiva granting wishes to his worshippers. I was hoping for some guidance on the way to worship him.

Comment: @ShivaMurary Try performing Mahamrutyunjaya Yagam for health related issues. But remember, it needs to chanted with knoweldgeable pundits (those know proper intonation) with faith, so getting them is bit tedious but if you are sincere, Shiva will even make the way easy for you. Also, take a vow. But sincerity is what Shiva sees. All the best!

Comment: @The Destroyer Thank you for the response but isn't that for people who're on verge of death or some sort? I mean Mrutyun Jaya.. The case with my brother isn't the same. He is mentally Ill more like a brain dead person.

Comment: @ShivaMurary No. It can used for any health related issues. Actually, [Mantra 6 - Anuvakam1 of Sri Rudram ,Mantras of Lord Rudra from very core portion of Vedas](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/stotra/Sri%20Rudram%20Anuvakam1.html) describe Parameswara as doctor who treats all kind of problems both bodily and spiritual. So, you can perform yagam for your brother with faith and leave result for Shiva.

Comment: Thank you so much for patiently responding. I'll speak to my dad to arrange for the yagnam. Shiva bless.

Comment: You may also chant medha dakshinamurty stotram in your brother's name.

Comment: Go to a priest of the Atharva veda. He will know the appropriate mantras.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Anugraham** (bestowing grace) is one of the fundamental characteristic of Lord Shiva. So, Lord Shiva certainly grants wishes. In the scripture also we find many many stories where Lord Shiva grants wishes to his devotees. Like giving son to Vyasa, Sanjivani Vidya to Sukra, Drinking poison on request by Devas, Giving Chandrahaans to Ravana etc... and so on. YajurVeda also after the Rudram section asks of many desires from it's Chamakam section. Similarly the Upanishads also speak the same. Eg. Svetasvatara Upanishad 6.13 states:

> नित्यो नित्यानां चेतनश्चेतनाना-
>                  **मेको बहूनां यो विदधाति कामान्** ।
>   तत्कारणं सांख्ययोगाधिगम्यं
>                  ज्ञात्वा देवं मुच्यते सर्वपाशैः ॥ १३॥
>  
>   He is the Eternal among the eternal, the Conscious among the conscious and **though non-dual, fulfils the desires of many.** He who has known Him, the luminous Lord, the Great Cause, to be realised by Knowledge and yoga, is freed from all fetters.

So, the thing is doing various methods so that Lord Shiva graces us. There are various methods provided in Puranas like Shiva Purana and Linga Purana which can be used to obtain various desires. Like; 
 
*1) Performing ShivaLinga Abhisekam 

2) Performing Sri Rudram Homam 

3) Performing MahaMrityunjaya Yajnam etc...*

These all methods should be done as per the methods given in Puranas and with the help of a good Priest.

There are also Nãma-Japa methods which can be used to invoke Grace of Lord Shiva. The most special is Shivas eight name which are very much emphasized in Vedas and Puranas. The [eight names](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10524/whats-the-relation-between-lord-shiva-and-lord-shani-dev/17075#17075) are:

> ● रुद्र (Rudra) 
>   ● भव (Bhava) 
>   ● सर्व (Sarva) 
>   ● ईशान (Ishana) 
>   ● पशुपति (Pashupati) 
>   ● भीम (Bhima) 
>   ● उग्र (Ugra) 
>   ● महादेव (Mahadeva)

These Eight names of Lord Shiva are very beneficial and chanting them can invoke grace of Lord Shiva. There are also [five names](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15124/how-rudra-became-shiva-in-vedas/15125#15125) which are also verified by Vedas:

> ● रुद्र (Rudra) 
>   ● भव (Bhava) 
>   ● सर्व (Sarva) 
>   ● शिव (Shiva) 
>   ● मृड (Mrida)

Chanting of these five names can also invoke grace of Lord Shiva. Similarly, chanting of the name '**Shiva**' is also highly emphasized in Shiva Purana. Hearing of stories related to Lord Shiva can also invoke grace of Shiva. And the Panchakshari Mantra '**Om Namaha Shivãya**' though seems simple is highly potent and the most emphasized mantra in Shiva and Linga Purana.

As a sidenote I discuss in my [answer here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12185/which-mantras-should-be-recited-to-properly-worship-lord-rudra/16878#16878) various mantras which can be used to worship Lord Shiva.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed explanation. I've been chanting the panchakshari mantra om namah shivaya everyday for as long as I can and will keep doing that in the future as well. Ty.

Comment: @Shiva Murary btw Linga Purana says that one should chant Panchakshari after getting the mantra from Priest/Guru... so it's better that you go to a Shiva temple and receive mantra from priest there... then it may be fully efficient... although one may also chant just by reading Purana...(but maybe fully efficient when received from priest)...